# Where can we find the "jboss.server.log.dir" in the wildfly configuration and how can override that variable or path ? Please mention therootpath

Tags: logging, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

Instead of changing in the domain.xml and the host.xml we need to edit in the  root path and if we try to change in the root path where it is setting the default path we use that and no need to edit all the configurations

I tried in the domain.xml and host.xml it is working and but all the remaining logs it is taking from the "Jboss.server.log.dir" , but in future we want to change again we need to  change all the log config files
, i need to know  where the exactly the "Jboss.server.log.dir" is getting intiated , Could please any one help this one

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're running in domain and you want to override where the managed serves write the logs. Is that that question?

Comment: Yes James , in domain mode